# regex whitesapce + linebreak

Tags: regex

I need to get all information inside **div** with **class="caixacampobranco"**
However, did not work. I'm not good with Regex.

Anyone knows hot to extract that especific information!?
I'll use, javascript(edited)

Here is entire the data:

https://gist.github.com/romuloinnocencio/43c5bcebe841501999bb

Comment: What **language**? And please use a parser instead of regular expression. Also it would help if you actually provide the data instead of linking to it along with your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I understand it you cannot use regular expressions in html as it is not a regular language. You can use a parser instead as I understand it.
[Link to more info](http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html)

Comment: Yeah, i will use javascript.

Comment: Right, if i'm supose not to use regex (htmlparsing.com/regexes.html), what I do?

Comment: You're going to use an HTML parser, but the specifics depend on what language you're using.  Note that htmlparsing.com has solutions for some languages in the sidebar on the left.

Comment: Andy's got you on the right track htmlparsing.com has the info. Thanks Andy. :)